# How To Append A Filename Within The Program After User Definition in C

Tags: c, string, append, concatenation

I have program that has the user entering the full path to the folder holding several datafiles.

for example
So say the user enters:

```
\\psf\Home\Desktop\HealthScore\HealthScore\DataFiles
```

I need to change it within the program to:

```
\\psf\Home\Desktop\HealthScore\HealthScore\DataFiles\BT_1.txt
```

I've tried adding the string together with one a pointer, the other is an array and with both parts being pointers.

Here is a sample of my latest attempt:

```
char filepath[1000];
FILE* fp;
char BP1_ext [] = "\\BP1.txt";

printf("Enter the path to the file holding the data files:");

            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", filepath);
            //////////////////////BLOOD PRESSURE//////////////////////
            if (bpSensors == 1)
            {
                filepath = (filepath + BP1_ext);
                fp = fopen(filepath, "r");
                if (fp == NULL)

                {
                    puts("ERROR OPENING FILES");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                else
                {
                    while (!feof(fp))
                    {
                        printf("\n\nREADING BP_1.txt...");
                        fgets(bp1_Line, 100, fp);
                        sscanf(bp1_Line, "%s\t%s\t%s", bp1_Val1, bp1_Val2, bp1_Val3);
                        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", bp1_Val1, bp1_Val2, bp1_Val3);
                    }
                    fclose(fp);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) to concatenate strings. sample usage will be

```
strcat (filepath, BP1_ext);
```

provided, `filepath` has enough room to hold the concatenated string.

That said,

1. `fflush(stdin)` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), don't use that.
2. Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Comment: Indeed on point 2, OP can make the loop like this: `while (fgets(bp1_Line, 100, fp) != NULL) {...}` and better move the `printf` cue outside the loop too.

Comment: i had it all consolidated because there are 25 different conditions i have to test and open various files depending on them, i only posted one of them because i felt like people wouldn't want or need to read through a few hundred lines of code. but, i will try out the suggested while loop, but i think im going to leave printf in the loop for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
filepath = (filepath + BP1_ext);
```

Use `strcat` to from `string.h` to concatenate your strings (`strcat(destionation, source)`):

```
strcat(filepath, BP1_ext);
```

Comment: okay. i did that. but would i still just use fp = fopen(filepath, "r")?                         and will i be able to change filepath multiple times then?                            for example can                                                                               strcat(filepath, BP1_ext);                                                                                   strcat(filepath, BP2_ext);                                                                                    be used at the same time without effecting each other?